# How to empty Actor dead letter queue

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

I have a use case where I'd like to empty my Akka actors' dead letter queues.

My local actor talks to a remote actor, sending it some data periodically.
I think these get queued up as when the remote actors becomes available, it gets a flood of events.

Is it possible to limit the size of this queue? Or even better access it, for clearing up the excess items based on some criteria? (at this point I'm even happy just clearing the whole thing up, or disabling this feature)

Comment: I've tried using a custom mailbox implementation, but that's the input queue. Based on the docs the output queue is "/deadLetters" on this case, but I am not able to access this to clear it up...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to clear it up. Per default it will just push the messages to the event bus: [See here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorRef.scala#L474). If there are no subscribers, it will just be thrown away: [See here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/event/EventBus.scala#L228).